# adverbial clause of cause without finite main clause

Tags: subordinate-clauses

> They stared at the girl weeping uncontrollably because she just lost her father.

My problem with this sentence is that the subordinate clause **because she lost her father** is a finite clause, but its corresponding main clause **weeping uncontrollably** is non-finite. Is this sentence grammatical?

Comment: There's no problem with the subordinate clause being finite (eg. "I **was crying** because I **cut** my finger"). The problem is that the sentence is somewhat ambiguous grammatically - did they stare because she lost her father, or was she weeping because she lost her father?

Comment: I guess the writer wanted to express that the girl was weeping because she lost her father. But that means the main clause of the subordinate clause would be non-finite.